# Can audio mute be configured to zero rather than off?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

Ubuntu 22.04

SPDIF on mobo connected to spdif2analogue converter, connected to stereo.

I upgraded my system hardware and installed Pipewire, and in the process have resolved many issues for audio and dual monitors. However, one issue remains.

The root problem is the stereo itself: when it is switched on or off, a power surge creates a thunderous thud from the bass box. To alleviate this, I simply leave the power on to the stereo. However, the issue is compounded by the volume control in Ubuntu 22.04. Whenever I use the speaker icon to reduce the volume to mute, and back to sound-on, the thud occurs both ways. Thus, Ubuntu, or Pulse, or Pipewire is effectively switching the power on and off to the stereo.

What I want is a mute that will reduce the volume to zero, *without* switching the power to the stereo off and on. So, can Alsa/Pulse/Pipewire be configured somehow ?

Comment: You could write a script that sets the volume to zero (using `amixer`), then assign that to a key combination. For bonus points, save the current volume in a file, and make the script a toggle.

Comment: @ Josh. Thanks for suggestion: interesting work-around, and I must learn how to do. 

Ultimately, I would like the Ausus on-board SPDIF audio to function in the same manner as the Nividia HDMI audio. 

Using the SPDIF (or audio jack), the system produces many thunderous thuds during power-on, before selecting a video, during power-off. I found a means to alleviate some thuds by adding a line, power_save=N, to the alsa config. But not all thuds. 

If I use the Nvidia HDMI port, into a hdmi2av converter, into the stereo, then NO thuds occur at any time during use.

Comment: PS. I can find no info anywhere hinting reasons why hdmi is clean audio when spdif produces the thuds. fyi, hdmi solves the thud problem, but creates a 2-monitor problem.